# F# Continuation-based tail-recursion

Tags: f#

I have a function

```
let rec f n = function | 0          -> 1
                       | k when k>0 -> n * (f n (k-1))
                       | _          -> failwith "illegal argument"
```

Which takes an `int n` and multiplies it by itself `k` times. Example:

```
f 3 3 
val it : int = 27
```

Now, I have rewritten it as a tail-recursive function to try and get a better understanding of it all:

```
let fT n y = 
    let rec loop acc = function
        | 0          -> 1
        | k when k>0 -> n * (loop acc (k-1))
        | _          -> failwith "illegal argument"
    loop 0 y
```

I'd be interested in doing the same using continuation-based tail-recursion, but I'm a little stuck on what it should do though:

```
let rec fC n c = 
    match n with
    | 0          -> c 1
    | k when k>0 -> n * (fC n (fun x -> ...) //Not sure what to do here
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the recursive case you need to construct another continuation which receives the result from the recursive call, then calls the initial continuation with the result multiplied by the current value of n:

```
let rec fC n y c =
    match y with
    | 0 -> c 1
    | k when k > 0 -> fC n (k-1) (fun r -> c (n * r))
    | _ -> failwith "illegal argument"
```

then

```
fT 3 3
> 27

fC 3 3 id
> 27
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I just noticed that the original `f` takes two arguments. So shouldn't it be `fC n k c = ...` ?

Comment: There's a case for composition `(c << (*) n)` instead of function application: You can reverse the order of execution more easily, if needed.